# Android studio Progress bar and count down timer

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, countdowntimer

I want to run the app for ten seconds and the progress starting from the begin.
Which should be the values of

```
progressBar.setProgress(100);
myCountDownTimer =  new MyCountDownTimer(10000, 1000);
```

and

```
 int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/100);
```

Here is the code i run:

```
package com.example.androidcountdownprogressbar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 Button buttonStart;
 ProgressBar progressBar;
 TextView textCounter;

 MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        textCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    progressBar.setProgress(100);
    myCountDownTimer =  new MyCountDownTimer(10000, 1000);
    myCountDownTimer.start();
   }});

    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

  public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
   super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   textCounter.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
   int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/100);
   progressBar.setProgress(progress);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
   textCounter.setText("Finished");
   progressBar.setProgress(0);
  }

    }

}
```